# How to refresh bootstrap wizard

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jsp

I have a jsp with a bootstrap wizard, like this:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/creativetim_bucket/products/22/original/wizard_template.png?1407329794

With this wizard, I can add the employees element collected in Javascript array (I also use AngularJS).

After that, in the last step of wizard there is the summary of the employees shown in a table. 
For each row of the table, I have been added an href link to delete the current employee element. This href link calls a function managed by AngularJS.

Ok, it work. But, after the deletion, the table is not refresh. And the deleted element is present in table yet, but not in array.

So, how can I refresh the table?

Here's the code of the table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>#</td>
                                                    <td>Nome</td>
                                                    <td>Cognome</td>
                                                    <td>Matricola</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tr ng-repeat="employee in listaDipendenti track by $index">
                                                <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                                                <td>{{employee.nome}}</td>
                                                <td>{{employee.cognome}}</td>
                                                <td>{{employee.matricola}}</td>
                                                <td><a ng-click="DeleteEmployees($index)" href="#" class="btn btn-simple btn-xs" role="button" style="color: green">Delete</a></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
```

Here's the code in JS:

```
//Classe di tipo Employee
        function Employee(nome, cognome, matricola) {
            this.nome = nome;
            this.cognome = cognome;
            this.matricola = matricola;
        }

        var listEmployees = [];
        var nDip = 0;

        function Controller($scope) {

        $scope.DeleteEmployees = function (n) {
                if (n > -1) {
                    listEmployees.splice(n, 1);
                }
            };
        }
```

Comment: you are using `ng-repeat` on `listaDipendenti` which isn't shown in your code but removing from array `listEmployees` which is a variable not even bound to the scope. Not sure how these 2 arrays are connected

Comment: I tried to change listaDipendenti with listEmployees, but it doesn't work.

Comment: should be removing from same array as is being displayed

Comment: Damn, you're right..

Answer (score 0):

for @charlietfl

It's not right, look the function used to add an employee in JS array.

```
$scope.AddInList = function () {
                var nome = $("#nome").val();
                var cognome = $("#cognome").val();
                var matricola = $("#matricola").val();

                $("#nome").val("");
                $("#cognome").val("");
                $("#matricola").val("");

                nDip = nDip + 1;
                listEmployees.push(new Employee(nome, cognome, matricola));

                $("#cont").text(nDip);
                $scope.listaDipendenti = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(listEmployees));

            };
```